# jquery - where to place youtube api script

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I am having the API youtube function, tried, it works ok on JsFiddle

But then I tried to put in the jquery block

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // youtube API script here but doesn' t works
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn' t works as before, am I doing something wrong ? how would I put the API script for it to work ?

[This is my actual code from JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/VSa9k/14/)

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem?  Your fiddle shows a YouTube video with "text to write here" over it.

Comment: Hi, yes, it should be pretty simple, when play the video, the "text comment" disappears, but if within the <script> </script> the API event is never called

Comment: Something else in your actual code (not the jsFiddle) is conflicting with it. Do you get any errors in your error console?